# select from mulitiple tables and then join

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new here and I hope I am asking my question correctly:
I am trying to implement search on forums database.
 I have 'questions' table and 'answers' table (they both related by 'id_question' field). I also have 'suggestions' table and 'comments' table that are also related.
In addition I have 'profiles' table which related to every table I've mentioned before by 'profile_id' field, this profiles table holds the information on the users.

I would like to implement wide search on specific fields ('topic', 'description'...)  in all the four tables I've mentioned before, and display those fields and the information of the user who wrote the post.
I really messed with this.
right now I have 4 queries (for each table), and each query makes  join with profiles table.
Do you know better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with INNER JOINS. I recommend starting with some simple INNER JOINS and building up your queries to be more inclusive and join more tables. It all depends on what you're trying to get, really. Be as precise as possible in returning exactly the information you want.

Here is a simple example and the assumptions I made:

Assuming the following
table: primarykey*, foreignkey#, othercolumns

```
questions: id_questions*, topic, description, profile_id#
answers: id_answers*, id_questions#, topic, description, profile_id#
suggestions: id_suggestions*, topic, description, profile_id#
comments: id_comments*, topic, description, profile_id#
user: profile_id*, name, details
```

KEYWORD: replace with your keyword or phrase

Look for a keyword in the questions and answers

```
SELECT * FROM questions q
INNER JOIN answers a
ON q.profile_id = a.profile_id
WHERE topic LIKE '%KEYWORD%'
OR description LIKE '%KEYWORD%';
```

Get the user profile for a user who used keyword in the questions and answers tables:

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u
INNER JOIN answers a
ON u.profile_id = a.profile_id
INNER JOIN questions q
ON q.profile_id = u.profile_id
WHERE topic LIKE '%KEYWORD%'
OR description LIKE '%KEYWORD%';
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: formatting.

Comment: Thank u very much! it is very helpfull, I need also posts from 'questions' which do not have related posts from 'answers' but I guess I can use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do it in four queries.

Otherwise you will get a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) as you try to join the tables.

Comment: This is the sort of thing best implemented with the [Map-Reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) pattern. If you can do it in parallel, even better.

Comment: @tadman, the question is about MySQL, and MySQL does not support map-reduce. I suggest you add your own answer and explain how map-reduce could be used for this problem, instead of down voting me.

Comment: I didn't down-vote you. I'm just saying if you can trigger four queries in parallel, then combine them in your application code, that's what you want to do.

Comment: Okay thanks for not down-voting me. MySQL only allows one query at a time on a given thread, so you'd have to use Gearman or something to farm them out to other workers in parallel. But regardless, that's not map-reduce, that's just running four different queries, which is what my answer says.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using UNION. Is not it?